# Cheapest Insertion is $2$-approximation for TSP

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, complexity, tsp, hamiltonian-paths

Consider the *Cheapest Insertion* Algorithm on a complete graph with $n$ vertices, where each edge $uv$ has a weight $w(uv)$, and the weights satisfy the triangle inequality $w(xz)\leq w(xy)+w(yz)$ for all $x,y,z$:

Start with any vertex $v_1$. Suppose at step $1\leq t \leq n$ we have a sequence of distinct vertices $s_t = (v_1, \dots, v_t)$. Pick $1\leq i \leq t$ and $u \notin \{v_1,\dots,v_t\}$ to minimise $w(v_iu)$. Define $s_{t+1}$ by inserting $u$ into $s_t$ after $v_i$. Output the Hamiltonian cycle defined by $s_n$.

I know that this is a $2$ approximation to the Metric Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP), but I am wondering how we could prove that this is actually the case.

Comment: How do you know it is a $2$-approximation? What is the motivation for the question?

Comment: @ChandraChekuri I have seen a few papers online stating that this is a $2$-approximation, but no proof was included so I couldn't see why this is the case and I haven't managed to prove it yet.

Comment: You may be aware of the MST heuristic that gives a 2-approximation. You can try to see if the algorithm can be viewed as implementing the MST heuristic.